# What is the formal definition of scalability?

Tags: scalability

When I read about the the definition of scalability on different websites. I came to know in context of CPU & software that it means that as the number of CPUs are added, the performance of the software improves.

Whereas, the description of scalability in the book on "An introduction to parallel programming by Peter Pacheco" is different which is as:

"Suppose we run a parallel program with a fixed number of processes/threads and a fixed input size, and we obtain an efficiency E. Suppose we now increase the number of processes/threads that are used by the program. If we can find a corresponding rate of increase in the problem size so that the program always has efficiency E, then the program is
scalable.
My question is what is the proper definition of scalability? and if I am performing a test for scalability of a parallel software, which definition among the two should I look be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

**Scalability** is an application's ability to function correctly and maintain an acceptable user experience when used by a large number of clients.

Preferably, this ability should be achieved through elegant solutions in code, but where this isn't possible, the application's design must allow for horizontal growth using hardware (adding more computers, rather than increasing the performance of one computer).

**Scalability** is a concern which **grows with the size of a business**. Excellent examples are Facebook ([video](https://youtu.be/QCHiNEw73AU)) and Dropbox ([video](https://youtu.be/PE4gwstWhmc)). Also, here's a [great explanation](https://youtu.be/-W9F__D3oY4) of various approaches to scalability from a session at Harvard.

**Scalability** also refers to the ability of a `user interface` to adapt to **various screen sizes** while maintaining the user experience.